# CSS Styling associated with Joomla menu type not located

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I have a menu called XYZ-spanish and created another one called XYZ-english. I want to apply the same CSS style to my new menu but it conditional based on the Joomla menu type name. The css it applies is in /web/templates/templatename/css/custom.css, but I have yet to find how it ties it to the menu-type name.

I have grepped through the whole directory tree with **grep -r 'XYZ-spanish' *** and **grep -r '.scrolltojsmenurightcustom' ***  which is the class name is applies to the menu. However I have checked the modules and none of them have any classes applied to them. The only clue I have that is I change the menu type name the styling gets removed. I'm going bananas looking for how it's applying it? Where should I look?

I have also searched through the database looking for both words and have yet to locate anything significant.

The only thing listed in the custom css is:

```
.scrolltojsmenurightcustom {
    color: #ff5c00 !important;
    padding-top: 0em !important;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on which menu system are you using, is your menu an extension? or part
 of your template?

Also you can use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or similar to inspect the source code of your page
 in your browser.

A tool like this will give you information about the selectors and the path where they are 
located, the line number and the name of the file that contains this selectors. Once you 
have this information you can add or change the values of the CSS.

Comment: It is a Joomla Module called JS-MENU. Very strange never seen this behavior before.